# Wrapping text inside a bound field in SPGridView

Tags: sharepoint, moss, web-parts

I am displaying some text in a column inside an SPGridView. The text happens to be more than a hunderd character long, and as a result, the webpart becomes too wide.

I tried setting BoundField.ItemStyle.Wrap to true, and I also tried BoundField.ControlStyle.Width and BoundField.ItemStyle.Width values but theyy didn't work...

How do i make the text wrap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column has its own width property - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.imm.sdk.sharepoint.medialibrary.column.width.aspx